# jQuery mobile Cross domain request

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have jQuery mobile app in which when users successfully logs in I have to show multi-page template content loaded through Ajax and json parsing dynamically.

Now when I am calling Ajax it always goes to error section only. but I checked in google chrome console the error sction recieved the return value . So why it is not going to success block

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <title>Insert title here</title>

        <script>
            (function($) {

                $.fn.getPageData = function() {
                    var finalData = "";

                    $.ajax({
                        url : "http://india.msg91.com/api/androidRoute4.php?user=admin_sapna&password=***********",
                        type : "GET",
                        success : function(data) {

                            finalData = '<div id="index" data-role="page" data-url="index" tabindex="0" class="ui-page ui-body-c ui-page-active" style="min-height: 386px;"><div data-role="header" class="ui-header ui-bar-a" role="banner"><h3 class="ui-title" role="heading" aria-level="1">First Page</h3></div></div>';

                        },
                        error : function(result) {
                            finalData = '<div id="index" data-role="page" data-url="index" tabindex="0" class="ui-page ui-body-c ui-page-active" style="min-height: 386px;"><div data-role="header" class="ui-header ui-bar-a" role="banner"><h3 class="ui-title" role="heading" aria-level="1">Error Page</h3></div></div>';

                        }
                    });
                    this.append(finalData);

                };

            })(jQuery);
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $('body').getPageData();
                //$(a).appendTo("body");
            });
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you probably should not post working creds for your api here.

Comment: You probably should not make your credentials available on the client side to begin with.

Comment: oh yeah, that too. :)

Comment: `this.append(finalData);` won't work outside the ajax callbacks, AJAX is asynchronous. Does login cause redirect to `https`? This would cause ajax error due to cross domain. Or is URL you are calling on same domain as page?

Comment: ajax = asynchronous ... your script should run into an error at this line `this.append(finalData);` if you didn't set up the ajax request with `async: false`. better put the `this.append` inside the success/error function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your previous post regarding the same issue, I believe that the problem is that you receive the error: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

This error appears when you have a client which tries to request data from a server residing in a different domain from where the client resides. You might want to use CORS or the JSONP technique (supports only GET requests) to deal with this issue.

Regarding **CORS**, you might want to read the [Access_control_CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) document from Mozilla Developer Network.

**JSONP** is used to request data from a server residing in a different domain. It allows a client to make cross site requests which would not be allowed using standard AJAX techniques. We need this technique to access data from a different domain and more specifically if protocol, port number, host is different from where data is being requested. These cross site requests interact with services which return JSON formatted data along with some additional padding. That's why it is called JSONP (JSON along with Padding).

A JSON payload is like: `{ "id" : "test", "message": "test message"}`. A JSONP payload is a JSON formatted object wrapped inside a function call like: `jsonpCallback( { "id" : "test", "message": "test messsage"});`

The below example is based on your code. You should check that your service on the server returns a JavaScript function call (callback) with the JSON data passed in as the argument (example: `jsonpCallback( { "id" : "test", "message": "test messsage"});`).

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
        <title>jQM JSONP Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function getData() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: "http://india.msg91.com/api/androidRoute4.php",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    jsonp : "callback",
                    jsonpCallback: 'jsonpCallback',
                    success: function() {
                       alert('success');
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert("Error: " + xhr.status + "\n" +
                               "Message: " + xhr.statusText + "\n" +
                               "Response: " + xhr.responseText + "\n" + thrownError);
                    }
                });
            }

            function jsonpCallback(data) {
                // do something with the response
                alert(data);
            }

            $(document).on( "pageinit", "#test-page", function( e ) {
                getData();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="test-page" data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1><a data-ajax="false" href="/">jQM JSONP Test</a></h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">   
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: what happens to the request, if the server doesn´t format the response as jsonpCallback ?

Answer (score 0):

add a datatype

like this for example `dataType: "html"`
you ajax func then becomes like this

```
$.ajax({
                    url : "http://india.msg91.com/api/androidRoute4.php?user=admin_sapna&password=!Passw0rd",
                    type : "GET",
                    dataType: "html",
                    success : function(data) {

                        finalData = '<div id="index" data-role="page" data-url="index" tabindex="0" class="ui-page ui-body-c ui-page-active" style="min-height: 386px;"><div data-role="header" class="ui-header ui-bar-a" role="banner"><h3 class="ui-title" role="heading" aria-level="1">First Page</h3></div></div>';

                    },
                    error : function(result) {
                        finalData = '<div id="index" data-role="page" data-url="index" tabindex="0" class="ui-page ui-body-c ui-page-active" style="min-height: 386px;"><div data-role="header" class="ui-header ui-bar-a" role="banner"><h3 class="ui-title" role="heading" aria-level="1">Error Page</h3></div></div>';

                    }
                });
```

you could also add `console.log("error" + result.status + result.statusText);`
inside the error block to try find out the error code and reason

Answer (score 0):

See what you have to do:

`form the docs:`

> The first thing you learn in jQuery is to call code inside the
>   $(document).ready() function so everything will execute as soon as the
>   DOM is loaded. However, in jQuery Mobile, Ajax is used to load the
>   contents of each page into the DOM as you navigate, and the DOM ready
>   handler only executes for the first page. To execute code whenever a
>   new page is loaded and created, you can bind to the pageinit event.

and order of scripts should be this way:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="custom-scripting.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-mobile.js"></script>
```

so your code order should look like this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
   (function($) {

      $.fn.getPageData = function() {
          var finalData = "";

          $.ajax({
              url : "http://india.msg91.com/api/androidRoute4.php?user=admin_sapna&password=***********",
              type : "GET",
              dataType :'html', //<---------need to specify what should be expected.
              success : function(data) {

              finalData = '<div id="index" data-role="page" data-url="index" tabindex="0" class="ui-page ui-body-c ui-page-active" style="min-height: 386px;"><div data-role="header" class="ui-header ui-bar-a" role="banner"><h3 class="ui-title" role="heading" aria-level="1">First Page</h3></div></div>';

                    },
              error : function(result) {
                        finalData = '<div id="index" data-role="page" data-url="index" tabindex="0" class="ui-page ui-body-c ui-page-active" style="min-height: 386px;"><div data-role="header" class="ui-header ui-bar-a" role="banner"><h3 class="ui-title" role="heading" aria-level="1">Error Page</h3></div></div>';

              }
          });
          this.append(finalData);
        };
        })(jQuery);
        $(document).on('pageinit', function () {
            $('body').getPageData();
        });
    </script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
```